# Saving c++ array of struct to file and issue for adding new elements to it

Tags: c++, arrays

There are two main problems with my program that I am currently having. The first is I am unable to add more than one account to my program while it is running (I need to close it and re-open before I can add another). The second issue is when I don't add any accounts to my program addresses get saved to the program, this is what the file looks like when I don't add any accounts to the program.

```
123#John Smith#0#0###-1.07374e+008#-1.07374e+008#
```

The first part of the file is correct, but the addresses are coming from somewhere else in memory. This is what my code looks like.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip> 
#include <string> 
#include <cmath> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

struct account
{
    string acctNum;
    string name;
    float cBal;
    float sBal;
};

int menu();
char subMenu();
int loadCustomers(account[]);
void saveCusomers(account[], int);
int newCustomer(account[], int);
int deleteCustomer(account[], int);
int findCustomer(account[], int);
void deposit(account[], int);
void withdrawl(account[], int);
void balance(account[], int);
void bankBalance(account[], int);

int main()
{
    account acc[20];
    int selection;
    int numAcc = 0;
    int search;

    numAcc = loadCustomers(acc);

    do
    {
        selection = menu();

        if(selection == 1)
        {
            newCustomer(acc, numAcc);
        }
        else if(selection == 2)
        {
            deleteCustomer(acc, numAcc);
        }
        else if(selection == 3)
        {
            search = findCustomer(acc, numAcc);

            if (search == -1)
            {
                cout << "That account doesn't exist." << endl;
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
            }
            else
            {
                cout << right << setw(3) << acc[search].acctNum << "" << left << setw(15) << acc[search].name << acc[search].cBal << acc[search].sBal << endl;
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
            }
        }
        else if(selection == 4)
        {
            deposit(acc, numAcc);
        }
        else if(selection == 5)
        {
            withdrawl(acc, numAcc);
        }
        else if(selection == 6)
        {
            balance(acc, numAcc);
        }
        else if(selection == 7)
        {
            bankBalance(acc, numAcc);
        }
        else if(selection == 8)
        {
            break;
        }
    } while (selection != 8);

    saveCusomers(acc, numAcc);

    return 0;
}

int menu()
{
    int select;

    cout << "Main Menu" << endl;
    cout << "=============" << endl;
    cout << "1. New Account" << endl;
    cout << "2. Delete Account" << endl;
    cout << "3. Find Customer" << endl;
    cout << "4. Deposit" << endl;
    cout << "5. Withdrawl" << endl;
    cout << "6. Balance" << endl;
    cout << "7. Bank Balance" << endl;
    cout << "8. Exit" << endl;
    cout << "=============" << endl;
    cout << "Enter choice: ";
    cin >> select;

    while (select < 1 || select > 8)
    {
        cout << "Invalid input, select a number between 1 and 8: ";
        cin >> select;
    }

    system("cls");

    return select;
}

char subMenu()
{
    char choice;

    cout << "Which account? <C>hecking or <S>aving: ";
    cin >> choice;

    while(choice != 'C' && choice != 'c' && choice != 'S' && choice != 's')
    {
        cout << "Invalid choice, choose either checking or saving: ";
        cin >> choice;
    }

    return choice;
}

int loadCustomers(account acc[])
{
    ifstream inFile;
    int numCustomers = 0, i = 0;
    string ctemp, stemp;

    inFile.open("customer.dat");

    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << "No customer file found." << endl;
    }

    else
    {   
        cout << "Customer file found..." << endl << endl;

        while (getline(inFile, acc[i].acctNum, '#'))
        {
            getline(inFile, acc[i].name, '#');
            getline(inFile, ctemp, '#');
            getline(inFile, stemp, '#');

            istringstream(ctemp) >> acc[i].cBal;
            istringstream(stemp) >> acc[i].sBal;
            i++;
            numCustomers++;
        }

        cout << "Number of customers found in file: " << numCustomers << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    system("cls");

    inFile.close();

    return numCustomers;
}

void saveCusomers(account acc[], int numCustomers)
{
    ofstream outFile;

    outFile.open("customer.dat");

    for (int i = 0; i < numCustomers; i++)
    {
        outFile << acc[i].acctNum;
        outFile << '#';
        outFile << acc[i].name;
        outFile << '#';
        outFile << acc[i].cBal;
        outFile << '#';
        outFile << acc[i].sBal;
        outFile << '#';
    }

    outFile << acc[numCustomers].acctNum;
    outFile << '#';
    outFile << acc[numCustomers].name;
    outFile << '#';
    outFile << acc[numCustomers].cBal;
    outFile << '#';
    outFile << acc[numCustomers].sBal;
    outFile << '#';

    cout << numCustomers + 1 << " accounts saved into the file." << endl;

    outFile.close();
}

int newCustomer(account acc[], int numCustomers)
{   
    cout << "New Customer" << endl;
    cout << "============" << endl;
    cout << "Enter account number: ";
    cin >> acc[numCustomers].acctNum;
    cout << "Enter name: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, acc[numCustomers].name);
    acc[numCustomers].cBal = 0;
    acc[numCustomers].sBal = 0;

    numCustomers++;

    return numCustomers;
}

int deleteCustomer(account[], int)
{

    return 0;
}

int findCustomer(account acc[], int numCustomers)
{
    string target;

    cout << "Enter the account number you are looking for: ";
    cin >> target;

    for (int i = 0; i < numCustomers; i++)
    {
        if (acc[i].acctNum == target)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

How can I change this to make it so I can add more than one account when the program is running, and how can I make it so the program won't save an address to my file when nothing is added? I would also like to know why those addresses are being saved like that.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to step through the code and see where it is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `main()` you `loadCustomers()` in `acc[]` and you keep a record of the number of customers in local variable `numAcc`.  At the end of `main()` you `saveCustomers()` the `numAcc` in `acc[]`.

**1. Your saving function is wrong:**

in your loop `for (int i = 0; i < numCustomers; i++) { ...}`, you first write each customer from 0 to `numAcc-1`.  This is correct.

But afterwards you write again an additional account, with the offset of `numAcc`.  So you're writng one more account than you have.  And the values of this account are not initialized, which explains the weird numbers you see.

You do this even if no account was added. And you know that you are doing it, because you've written `cout << numCustomers + 1 << " accounts saved into the file."`

***Correction:***  just save the accounts you have, in the loop.

**2.Your adding function is correct but you don't use it as you've planned:**

When you add a customer with `newCustomer()` your function increments its local variable so that it knows that there is one more customer.  Your function correctly returns this new number.

Unfortunately, in main() you do nothing with this returned value, so that numAcc remains unchanged.

***Correction:***  Correct the following statement in `main()`:

```
    if (selection == 1)
    {
        numAcc = newCustomer(acc, numAcc);   // update the number of accounts
    }
```

**3. Miscellaneous remarks:**

You don't check in `newCustomers()` if your acc[] array is already full.  If you add a 21st account, it'll be a segfault !

The same applies to load.  You cannot be sure that nobody added a line to the file with a text editor. So there is as well a risk of reading more lines that there is space in your arry.

Nothing happens in `deleteCustomer()` I suppose you haven't written it yet.  Think that this function could change the number of accounts, exactly as `newCustomer()`.

As most banks have more than twenty customers, I assume that it's an exercise for school.  I don't know if you're allowed to do so, but I'd highly recommend to replace arrays with [`vectors`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).